# Apache2 Container on BlueMix won't stay up

Tags: apache, docker, containers, ibm-cloud, dockerfile

I've started with IBM's image:

```
registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
```

It's Ubuntu 14.04, I then add Apache2 on, do some file copies of my site, and then EXPOSE 443. Lastly, I invoke a bash script with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
rm -f /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid
exec /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
```

When I run the container locally, it works fine and serves up what I need. When BlueMix builds from the Dockerfile, that works without error. Then deploys to a container successfully. Immediately after deploy, the container registers as 'STOPPED'. Restarting brings it up and then back down within a few seconds. 'cf ic logs my-process-id' doesn't show any feedback.

Other things I've tried:
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
Using service apache2 restart

Dockerfile:

```
FROM registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest

RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y nano


# ADD SSL
RUN a2enmod ssl
RUN a2enmod proxy_http


WORKDIR /var/www/dist
RUN mv ./* /var/www/html

COPY docker/httpd-foreground.sh /usr/local/bin/
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["httpd-foreground.sh"]
```

httpd-foreground.hs:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
rm -f /usr/local/apache2/logs/httpd.pid
exec /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND
```

Comment: Any logs? Containers stop when the main application (PID 1) stops.

Comment: None. And furthermore, I built the docker container locally, registered it with BlueMix registry, deployed it to a container and poof, it works fine. So the issue is limited to when the Dockerfile is processed and built within the BlueMix Build stage.

Comment: can you post the Dockerifle? Or at least show the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` entries.

Comment: Updated with script and with dockerfile above.

Comment: Weird. Can you try to debug and see if the exec part is returning immediately? Your bash script is PID 1 so the `exec` command should not return because it would close. Without any logs that's hard. You can also try to force wait the apacheprocess to finish removing the `exec` and `-DFOREGROUND` and putting `&` at the end, and then put `waitpid $!` in the next line.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is getting node image, installing apache and overriding the command, and trying to run in the foreground. This is not really a good way to run a apache container on bluemix.

You should do something like this:
 1. Follow information in here to pull the **httpd** image to your local, push the local image to your bluemix name space.
 - docker pull httpd:2.4
 - docker tag httpd:2.4 registry.ng.bluemix.net//httpd
 - docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net//http
 2. Once the image is pushed to your namespace, you can create custom image with your Dockerfile, note that I assume you have your website content in public-html folder

> FROM registry.ng.bluemix.net//httpd:2.4 COPY ./public-html/
>   /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ EXPOSE 80

3. Build your image

> ```
> cf ic build --tag myhttp .
> ```

4. Run the container:

> ```
> cf ic run --name myhttp -p 80 registry.ng.bluemix.net/<yourNameSpace>/myhttp
> ```

5. Bind IP address, using

> ```
> cf ic bind <IP> myhttp
> ```

6. Access your container with the IP you bound

Comment: I appreciate the answer, however this leaves me with concerns. You haven't addressed the issues in the BM pipeline. Why does it not produce the same outcome when BM builds from the dockerfile as it does when I build it locally. Should be symmetry there. And second, I should be able to run an apache server from any base image, assuming I set up Apache right. Why should someone have to start with a specific HTTPD image when the whole point of Docker is building whatever you like?